# Convert JCalendar event c.getTime() to SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, jcalendar

I want to convert the selected date into the format"dd-MM-yyyy" because c.getTime returns "Sun Mar 3 12:34:46 IST 2013"

private class MyDateListener implements DateListener {

```
    public void dateChanged(DateEvent e) {

        Calendar c = e.getSelectedDate();
        if (c != null) {
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat(c.getTime().toString());
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                Date date;
                date = parser.parse(date1);
                output = formatter.format(date);
                System.out.println(output);
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Example1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("No time selected.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean I'm unable to to convert the selected date into the format"dd-MM-yyyy" because c.getTime returns "Sun Mar 3 12:34:46 IST 2013"

Comment: Any ideas for the conversion please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
System.out.println(sdf.format(c.getTime());
```

The [getTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime%28%29) function actually returns a date, which you can pass to your formatter, so there is no need to parse it.